# How to add instance declaration for Typeable

Tags: haskell

> [...] wants to find all the places in a legacy codebase that a variable foo is used in the conditional of an if.
>
> ———— [Why Haskell Is Worth Learning](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/03/05/why-haskell/)

the code I have is

```
import Language.C
import Data.Generics
import Control.Monad
import Text.Read
    
parseAndFindFoos :: FilePath -> IO (Either ParseError [Position])
parseAndFindFoos path = liftM (fmap findFooLocations) (parseCFilePre path)
findFooLocations input = fmap posOf (listify isIfOfInterest input)
isIfOfInterest (CIf cond _ _ _) = not (null (listify isFooIdent cond))
isFooIdent (Ident name) = (name == "foo")
```

how could I add an instance declaration for (Typeable Lexeme)?

Answer (score 8):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, StandaloneDeriving #-}
import Data.Typeable

deriving instance Typeable Lexeme
```

should work.

There is one pitfall, however, and this only really applies if this instance is to be defined in a library.  `Lexeme` will be made an instance of `Typeable`, and if any other library includes a similar instance, there will be a conflict.  Unfortunately, all you can really to ensure that you don't add the global `Typeable` instance of `Lexeme` is either hope it gets added to `base` at some point, or use a `newtype` wrapper and manually wrap and unwrap `Lexeme`.

```
newtype LexemeWrapper = WrapLexeme { unwrapLexeme :: Lexeme } deriving Typeable
```